# sigabrt error calling segue programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS development and am currently attempting to call a segue programmatically after a cell in a `UITableViewController` is selected. Although I already created the segue in my storyboard and assigned it an identifier, I still receive a sigabrt error at the `performSegueWithIdentifier` method call within an overridden `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) 
{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toExerciseInfo", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Did you connect the segue to a particular cell or to the view controller as a whole?  Also, "sigabrt" is not very useful...can you give the complete error output to the console?

Comment: the whole view controller. this is the most useful piece of info I could recover from the console: 

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<LiftMate.ExerciseInfoViewController 0x7fd931f80800> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key RepEntr.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called

Comment: and on second though, something is telling me it has to do with the destination view controller rather than the segue.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  Luckily key value coding-compliant errors are usually very easy to fix.  More often than not they're storyboard related.

Comment: what's especially confusing is the fact that there is no variable named "RepEntr." in the class

Comment: is it in storyboard?

Comment: okay, i found the problem. it turns out that the view controller was referencing an older version of the class stored outside the project directory, so it got conflicting data from that and the class within the project. thanks for all your help. really appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old post, but it showed up at the top of a google search and I was able to solve my problem by reading the comments. Just to pay it forward...

This is a problem that can occur when you have a bad connection from your storyboard to the view controller. In my case, I'd connected a button to an outlet, then deleted the outlet, leaving a dangling connection. I was able to fix it fairly easily by ctrl+clicking the view in the storyboard, visually inspecting the connections listed, and then deleting the one that was no longer valid. I'm sure there are other ways to fix the error, but that's what worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

This might help someone someday.

Make sure you call the segue on the main thread or it will crash (SIGABRT):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"customplayer" sender:self];
            });
```

Comment: This question is about Swift, not Objective-C.