# performSegue throwing SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, segue

This code is *supposed to* have a button get clicked, a segue be performed and the encrypted data get passed to the second view controllers' var called *passedData*.
Here is the code for the button action:

```
@IBAction func encodePressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if messageInput.hasText {
        encodedMessage = encodeMessage(input: messageInput.text!)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showEncoded", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

For the prepareForSegue I have this code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? secondVC {
        if let message = encodedMessage {
            destinationViewController.passedData = message
        }
    }
}
```

The line that says "performSegue" is the one that is throwing the SIGABRT error. Please comment if you need any more info and I will not hesitate to add more info.

BTW, my question was already answered in the comments by Aaron Halvorsen. Do not hesitate to put an answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513134/sigabrt-error-calling-segue-programatically-in-swift, look here and see if that solves it.

Comment: @AaronHalvorsen Thank you, This answered my question!

Comment: Your view controller probably doesn't have a segue called `showEncoded`, double check that. PS. For future reference, you should check what the console says when you get an error, `SIGABRT` doesn't say a lot, it literally just says that the execution was aborted, but I'm pretty sure that the console in Xcode says that it didn't find a segue with the name you specified.

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace of the SIGABRT error? Chances are it might indicate the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[sigabrt error calling segue programatically in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513134/sigabrt-error-calling-segue-programatically-in-swift)

Make sure you don't have any orphaned connections from your view controller to your storyboard.